# What is the .git/branches folder used for?

Tags: git

I have always assumed that the `.git/branches` directory is for legacy purposes and that git used to use that directory, but now uses the `.git/refs` directory instead.  Is this true? If not, then what is the purpose of that directory since I have never seen it used or referenced.

EDIT

I'm using git version 1.7.3.4.

Comment: I don't have a branches directory in any of the checkouts I have to hand (all git 1.7.9 I think) - maybe it's deprecated and now gone?

Comment: git 1.7.9.5, 1.7.9.1, 1.7.5.4 and I always get a branches folder, though empty.

Comment: I could not find any better reference than [this link](http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/git/directory.htm), which confirms that it is a deprecated way to ref branches.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The now "slightly deprecated" use of `.git/branches` is described in the useful [`gitrepository-layout` documentation](http://schacon.github.com/git/gitrepository-layout.html):

> **branches**: A slightly deprecated way to store shorthands to be used to specify URL to *git fetch*, *git pull* and *git push* commands is to store a file in *branches/<name>* and give *name* to these commands in place of repository argument.

In the comments above, the question was raise of why some people have this directory and some don't.  It seems that [a commit was introduced in 2009](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0cc5691a8b05a7eabdeef520c94b1bb3bcac7874) that stopped git from creating the `.git/branches` directory by default.  However, more recently that change [was reverted](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c8a58ac5a52b0850fbca87898d1c6aa44cf5626f) (i.e. meaning that the `.git/branches` *will* be created on `git init`, etc.), with the following justification from Junio C. Hamano:

> There is not enough justification for doing this.  We do not update
>   things in *.git/branches* and *.git/remotes* anymore, but still do read
>   information from there and will keep doing so.
>
> Besides, this breaks quite a lot of tests in t55?? series.

Comment: The link to the git repository layout documentation is no longer working. Do you know if it's available somewhere else?
EDIT: nvm, I found it. https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrepository-layout