# Create a remote git repository and push from local

Tags: git

These are my steps to create a remote git repository and push to it the data that I have in my local machine:

```
# mkdir -p git/sports.git
# cd git/
# cd sports.git/
# git init --bare
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/tirengarfio/git/sports.git/
# exit
logout
Connection to 173.203.57.258 closed.
(master)]$ git remote add origin ssh://root@173.203.57.258/home/tirengarfio/git/sports.git
(master)]$ git push --all
root@173.203.57.258's password: 
Counting objects: 1271, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (1236/1236), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1271/1271), 1.11 MiB, done.
Total 1271 (delta 37), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ssh://root@173.203.57.258/home/tirengarfio/git/sports.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

When I go to `/home/tirengarfio/git/sports.git/branches` it is empty..

Comment: And what exactly is your question?

Comment: @iblue my question is: where are the files that i pushed? I expected they were inside the folder branches or any other part inside sports.git folder..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this answers your question(s)...

### Where are my files?

Git does not store the files in plain. It compresses them and stores then in a tree (and in so called packfiles). There is an article on gitready that explains the directory structure. For more details, you could refer to the manpage I linked below.

- [what's inside your .git directory](http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/03/23/whats-inside-your-git-directory.html)

For details about the internal format, please see chapter 9 of the Pro Git book. Here is an online version:

- [Pro Git - Git Internals](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals)

### Why is the branches directory empty?

The `branches` directory seems to exist only for legacy purposes. Which is documented in [`man 5 gitrepostory-layout`](http://schacon.github.com/git/gitrepository-layout.html):

> `branches`
>
> A slightly deprecated way to store shorthands to be used to specify URL to git fetch, git pull and git push commands is to store a file in branches/ and give name to these commands in place of repository argument.

For more details, see: [What is the .git/branches folder used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10398225/what-is-the-git-branches-folder-used-for)

### How do I get the files out of the `.git` directory?

If you just want to access your files, the simplest way would be to clone your repository.

```
$ git clone /home/tirengarfio/git/sports.git/
```